# How to label yield call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, odata

In the following yield call I need to label each result. In the link: [https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/](http://%20https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects), there is an example but I am unable to relate to that as I am using map here. The label I want to use here is obtained from another array. So for each element of label array there should be a yield call.

I want to use label so that I can relate to what response to which item? Also I don't want `yield call` to throw error as soon as one request fails and I want to make `yield call` to wait until all calls are completed and then throw any errors. How can I achieve them and how can I make use of that label from the result of each call?

```
const apiCall = async (
    client: ServiceRootClient,
    item: itemReq
): Promise<any> => {
    const results = await client
        .(some unrelated stuff)
        .execute();

    return results;
};

export labelArray = {
  id: string
}

export item = {
  attribute1: string;
  attribute2: string;
  attribute3: string;
}

const items : item[] = [{
    attribute1: "bal.blah..",
    attribute2:  "bal.blah..",
    attribute3:  "bal.blah.."
}, {
    attribute1: "bal.blah..",
    attribute2:  "bal.blah..",
    attribute3:  "bal.blah.."
}];

const labelArr : labelArray[] = [
  {
        id: "1st item"
  },
  {
        id: "2nd item"
  }
];

  const result = yield all([id: // id is from labelArr 
            items.map(item => call(apiCall, action.metadata.client, item))
        ]);
```

Thanks in advance